# PHP, yii framework gives error on update/insert, select works fine

Tags: php, mysql, yii, windows-server

when i use db on shared mysql, yii add/update works fine, but when i move the database to my windows machine in local mysql i get error : Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sp_1' cannot be null.

full error
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sp_1' cannot be null. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `user_details` SET `id`=:yp0, `user_id`=:yp1, `country_id`=:yp2, `state`=:yp3, `city`=:yp4, `county`=:yp5, `address`=:yp6, `address2`=:yp7, `zipcode`=:yp8, `lng`=:yp9, `lat`=:yp10, `zoom`=:yp11, `created`=:yp12, `last_login`=:yp13, `phone_no`=:yp14, `fax_no`=:yp15, `paypal_email`=:yp16, `company_title`=:yp17, `company_description`=:yp18, `company_logo`=:yp19, `bill_name`=:yp20, `bill_address`=:yp21, `bill_country_id`=:yp22, `pro_cap_aerospace`=:yp23, `pro_cap_helicopter`=:yp24, `pro_cap_defence`=:yp25, `pro_cap_other`=:yp26, `pro_cap_benefit_1`=:yp27, `pro_cap_benefit_2`=:yp28, `pro_cap_busi_1`=:yp29, `pro_cap_busi_2`=:yp30, `pro_cap_busi_3`=:yp31, `pro_cap_busi_4`=:yp32, `pro_cap_busi_5`=:yp33, `pro_cap_busi_6`=:yp34, `pro_cap_busi_7`=:yp35, `pro_cap_busi_8`=:yp36, `pro_cap_busi_9`=:yp37, `pro_cap_busi_10`=:yp38, `pro_cap_busi_11`=:yp39, `pro_cap_busi_12`=:yp40, `pro_cap_busi_13`=:yp41, `pro_cap_busi_14`=:yp42, `pro_cap_busi_15`=:yp43, `pro_cap_busi_16`=:yp44, `pro_cap_busi_17`=:yp45, `pro_cap_busi_18`=:yp46, `pro_cap_busi_19`=:yp47, `pro_cap_busi_20`=:yp48, `pro_cap_busi_21`=:yp49, `pro_cap_busi_company`=:yp50, `pro_cap_eq_1`=:yp51, `pro_cap_eq_2`=:yp52, `pro_cap_eq_3`=:yp53, `pro_cap_eq_4`=:yp54, `pro_cap_eq_5`=:yp55, `pro_cap_eq_6`=:yp56, `pro_cap_eq_7`=:yp57, `pro_cap_eq_8`=:yp58, `pro_cap_eq_9`=:yp59, `dp_third_party_certy`=:yp60, `dp_iso_certy`=:yp61, `dp_nadcap_certy`=:yp62, `dp_militry_certy`=:yp63, `dp_civil_certy`=:yp64, `dp_quality_org`=:yp65, `dp_qpl_certy`=:yp66, `dp_cont_org_1`=:yp67, `dp_cont_org_2`=:yp68, `dp_various_overseen`=:yp69, `dp_various_pcont`=:yp70, `dp_various_result`=:yp71, `dp_various_level`=:yp72, `dp_various_civil`=:yp73, `dp_various_date`=:yp74, `bd_iban`=:yp75, `bd_amount`=:yp76, `bd_bic`=:yp77, `bd_country_id`=:yp78, `bd_cin`=:yp79, `bd_swift`=:yp80, `bd_bank_name`=:yp81, `bd_bank_location`=:yp82, `sp_1`=:yp83, `sp_2`=:yp84, `sp_3`=:yp85, `sp_4`=:yp86, `sp_5`=:yp87, `sp_6`=:yp88, `sp_7`=:yp89, `sp_8`=:yp90, `sp_9`=:yp91, `sp_10`=:yp92, `sp_11`=:yp93, `certification`=:yp94, `certification_type`=:yp95 WHERE `user_details`.`id`=48

Comment: `Column 'sp_1' cannot be null`. Is the DB the same structure on both environments? Where is the `:yp83` binding?

Comment: yes both are same structure,only difference i can see is version. local server: 5.7.13- and shared server version is 5.6.26

Answer (score 0):

"Column 'sp_1' cannot be null".
Could you check if `sp_1` is a not null column or not.
Maybe in the old environment all values of `sp_1` are not null.
But in the new environment you set a null value for it.

Comment: this works. but same db structure, same data, same php yii code. does not work with db(local windows machine with mysql 5.7.13) but works on shared hosting my sl 5.6.26. i have around 50+ tables, i dont think i should go and check each table to resolve like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem recently. what you can do is to solve your problem is go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and open structure of the table and click on edit button of `sp_1` and check the null checkbox as you can see in below image.
[phpmyadmin_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5lwr.png)

Comment: this works. but same db structure, same data, same php yii code. does not work with db(local windows machine with mysql 5.7.13) but works on shared hosting my sl 5.6.26. i have around 50+ tables, i dont think i should go and check each table to resolve like this.